# Visual Studio Step into(F11) does not work in new Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests

I have a Selenium Automation test project in VisualStudio 2015 with Default configuration. I recently added a new configuration and while debugging test cases in the new configuration , the F11 step into is not working.
Please Help!

Solved: Under Build configuration, select the advanced setting and set debug output to 'Full'. See image below.

[Correct Debug Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HokZT.png)

Comment: Are you sure you solution is at debug mode ? you may forgot project at release mode .

Comment: I am debugging the test case in the new configuration.. So mode will be (New config).

Comment: Are the breakpoints firing ?

Comment: breakpoint at test level fire. But breakpoints inside function are skipped.

Comment: Can you right click the project and check the debug tab the configuration is (Active)Debug ?

Comment: I see only two options there under debug tab : Start new instance and Step into Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Under Build configuration, select the advanced setting and set debug output to 'Full'. See image below.

[image: Correct Debug Settings]